# Server Error TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js, github-actions

I am working on a Next.js project and I am encountering an error while generating a page. The error message is

```
"TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function".
```

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to resolve it. I have tried searching for solutions online but have not found anything that has worked. Can someone please help me understand what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Error when built to prod. Build works fine, pages are generated but when pushed to the cloud this is what i see.

```
"TypeError: (0 , react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsxDEV) is not a function"
```

NODE_VERSION | 16.x

NODE_ENV | production

Comment: Any update about this? Facing the same error.